# rigid body simulation not rendered correctly

Tags: python, rigid-body-simulation

I would like to replace objects at the end of a rigid body simulation by a another object. But the final scene contains the old ones, even when I call `obj.hide=True` on the original object. The new objects ARE in the scene, but on the pose where the simulation started not at the final frame.

What the replace function does:
Traversing a list of objects to be replaced. Copy a "template" object and put it to the location of the original object.

```py
def duplicate_and_replace(lst_obj,obj_name):

    scn = bpy.context.scene
    obj_name_rgb = obj_name.replace("tex", "rgb")
    obj_rgb = bpy.data.objects[obj_name_rgb]

    for obj in lst_obj:
        new_obj = obj_rgb.copy()
        new_obj.data = obj_rgb.data.copy()
        new_obj.animation_data_clear()
        scn.objects.link(new_obj)
        new_obj.location = obj.location
        new_obj.rotation_euler = obj.rotation_euler
        obj.hide=True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works for me now:

```
new_obj.location = obj.matrix_world.translation
new_obj.rotation_euler = obj.matrix_world.to_euler()
```